# Exit button for jquery mobile app that is built using phonegap build service

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

How to add an exit button in `JQuery mobile footer` for `android devices.`

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="site-menu">
    <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="exit">exit</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The handler for `id="exit".`

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(){
    $("#exit").on("vclick", function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        // navigator.app.exitApp(); 
       /*
        As there is no inclusion on phonegap.js
        file this does not work.
       */
    });
});
```

This is in `plain jquery mobile`. Now we are building this `using phonegap build service`. The above code does not work in browser before build and after build by the `.apk` file that is installed on the device.

So how the `exit button` should be implemented for  `web apps` built using `phonegap build sevice` ?

Comment: are your trying to close the browser window ?

Comment: Yes. That is not possible due to security reasons